# Does caller activity's ondestroy() always gets called after the called activity's oncreate() or there are exceptions?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am opening an `activity` with also `destroying` the caller activity(*activity from which we are calling intent*). Now I wanted to ask Does caller activity's `ondestroy()` always gets called after the called activity's `oncreate()` or there are exceptions ??

Caller Code is given below.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
finish();
```

Currently what is happening is `ondestroy()` method is always getting called after the `oncreate()` but I wanted to know will it happen always or not ??

Comment: I think what's really important is that the calls to `onDestroy` and `onCreate` are queued in the main thread (in either order) without any possibility for anything else (like the `onPostExecute` of an `AsyncTask`) to intervene.  I've relied on this behavior, but I'd also like to know whether it's documented.

Answer (score 1):

Lifecycle of activities are managed by Android runtime and you can not change its behavior. If you start a new activity, Android normally keeps caller Activity alive so if you press back on the new Activity, caller activity opens fast (without calling its `onCreate`).

More about Activity lifecycle [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Sorry, but my question is as I am finishing my caller activity now I want to know how android manage both activities lifecycle(caller activity will gets destroyed first or new activity will gets created first) ??  thanks for answering anyways :)

Comment: Calling finish to an activity will not necessarily destroy or even stops an activity. The only thing that this call does is moving android from foreground to background and removing it from task. Not anything more.

Comment: Then why when I am seeing in my logs ondestroy() is getting called every time ?? It means it is getting destroyed.

Comment: These methods are callbacks. it means that every time android decides to pause, stop or destroys an activity, calls this methods so you can do what you should do in that state.

Comment: Ok then according to you if I will press back button then my caller activity could have opened, because as you are saying it's upto android runtime ?? So maybe my activity is still in back stack but that doesn't happen ??

Comment: Even if you will say that depend upon Android runtime, now my question is, Is there any surety which step will happen first or not ??

Comment: after you leave an activity, these methods will be called in order: onPause, onStop and onDestroy. Lifecycle of second activity is completely independent and for example you can not say that onStop of first activity is called before onCreate of second activity.

Comment: Yes but as I am seeing in my logs in near around 1000 cases ondestroy() is getting called later, so maybe this happens everytime ?? Don't you think so. Also thanks for constantly replying to my question here.

Comment: Sure, but the point is you have not control of this lifecycle and you can only add your business logic (i.e. store state of the activity or something like that) in those callbacks

Comment: Yes, I will do that, but if someone knows that this happens every time then I won't. So actually just waiting for an answer here. Also, this functionality I have done in many cases and changing everything will take a lot of time, so that's why I wanted to know.

Comment: from Google docs: "The system’s **likelihood** of killing a given process—along with the activities in it—depends on the state of the activity at the time"